# Getting access denied when raising property changed

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a class defined like this (i have removed some code lines, like null checks, to keep it short):

```
public sealed class CodeTheme : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public void Reload()
    {
        PropertyChanged(sender, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyProperty"));
    }

    public Thickness MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return new Thickness():
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

I am registering the codetheme class in XAML like this, using the StandardStyles.xaml

```
<me:CodeTheme x:Key="Theming" />
```

Than, i am using it in varios templates and styles, like so:

```
<Style x:Key="Style1" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource Theming}, Path=MyProperty}" />
</Style>
```

I then i might call the `Reload` method at any time in the program, the first time in the overwritten `OnLaunched` event of the App.xaml.cs

This works for colors, strings and other Thickness values when i assign them in `DataTemplate`. However when i use it in a `Style`, i get the following error as soon as i fire the `PropertyChanged` event:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled by user code
>     HResult=-2147024891
>     Message=Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
>     Source=System
>     StackTrace: (i have removed this)
>     InnerException:

I have tried to raise the event by `RunAsync` from the `Window.Current.Dispatcher` but that didnt change anything. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure PropertyChanged is not null?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt Yes i am totally sure, for there IS a null check in the original source (as i mentioned in my first sentence, i have removed some lines to keep it short)

Comment: Having a bit more of the stack trace would probably be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bindings were not supported in Style Setters last time I checked.

Comment: Yeah, they should evaluate OneTime though - and they do! The problem is the moment i am calling Reload(), which is in OnLaunched. Any other time it doesnt crash! To be clear, i dont need the binding to refresh, i just dont want it to crash.